# Struggling to understand vulkan's uniforms

Tags: vulkan

After a first game engine in rust + openGL, I tried out Vulkan.

I've been following [this tutorial](https://kylemayes.github.io/vulkanalia/) (as it is in rust) but it seems to be a rust version of the [original vulkan tutorial](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/).

I've done most of the set up, and I'm failing to grasp how uniform buffers are meant to work. I think I understood correctly how descriptor set/pools works, but I can't seem to figure out how to properly use uniform buffers.

In my current model, I have :

- pipeline are a vert + frag shaders, that tells "how" to draw objects.
- materials reference a pipeline, with materials properties that work with the pipeline.

Ideally, each pipeline would have their uniforms, because different type of shaders would have different needs.

For the camera, I created a buffer sized with the number of in flight frames, and each frame I write to the sub part of the buffer the camera view + projection matrices.

Now, I'm trying to add model matrix uniforms. If I want to follow what I'm doing, I have to create a huge buffer, that is the size of number of objects * number of in flight frames ? and each frames, I update part of the buffer, for the specific frame ? it feels like this is a really big buffer. And I'm pretty sure I would need an exact same size buffer for materials.

I would like to know what is the "usual" way to handle this, and if this is what is needed. I'm still learning and struggling with some Vulkan concepts, so please correct me if I got anything wrong.

Comment: There is no "usual way" here. Even the setup you describe with the camera matrix is not a "usual way"; it's just one way to make it work. It all depends on what kinds of scenes you're working with.

Comment: I'd question the "really big buffer" part of this. When compared to the actual object data (vertices and textures) your total uniform size is very likely to be insignificant in terms of both footprint and bandwidth.